# Optimization- Finding element of list which has maximum no. of divisors present in list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-tree

```
Eg. [2,8,4,2]
8 has divisors 2,8,4,2
4 has divisor 2,4,2
2 has divisor 2,2
```

Thus 8 has the maximum no of divisors present in the list.
I can think of O(n^2) algorithm (sort and then brute force) but is there any more optimized solution?

Edit: updated the example.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the divisors of 8 are 2,8,2 but the divisors of 6 is only 2. Why doesn't 6 have divisors 2,6,2?

Comment: The answer is probably no - simply because the output size can be O(n^2)... If you will change the output format maybe it will be possible.

Comment: @Yonlif Output size is O(1). The answer to the example in the question is just `8`.

Comment: Correct, the output confused me. sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up in the example. Fixing it thanks. @Yonlif I still think there could be a better solution because there are some repeated calculation, if we can store this in tree or a different data structure, may be more optimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasonable value range:

Put all values into map.

Find all divisors of every number in `O(sqrt(value))` and check if they are in the map

Complexity is `O(n*sqrt(maxvalue))`